# Display rows of a 2d array in reverse order

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop

I'm working on an app that is a "poor man's matrix" ie. 1 and 0 fall down the screen.

So far I have managed to get the 2d array to display one row on 1st user input, 2 rows on 2nd user input, 3 rows on 3rd user input etc.

The problem is, that the 1st row always stays at the top and I can't get the "drop-down" effect. It always appends an additional row of 1 and 0 bellow the previous row/row on user input.

Example - how it works so far:

my 2d array:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 (2nd row)
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 (3rd row)
1 0 0 1 0 1 0 (4th row)
```

1st user input (`Console.ReadKey();`):

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
```

2cnd user input (`Console.ReadKey();`):

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 (2nd row)
```

3rd user input:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 (2nd row)
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 (3rd row)
```

etc.

What I would like to achive is something similar but in "reverse" order.

Example - what I would like to achive:

1st user input:

```
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
```

2cnd user input:

```
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 (2nd row)
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
```

3rd user input:

```
0 0 1 0 1 0 1 (3rd row)
0 1 0 1 0 1 0 (2nd row)
1 0 1 0 1 1 1 (1st row)
```

So, to summerise, I would like to modify my existing code, so that the 1st row is always added last. Or possible start reading from the end of the array - last row. I have tried this, but I constantly get `outOfRange` error...

Any help would be welcome.

The code that just adds additional rows below an existing one:

```
public static int row = 0;
static void PrintRelevantLines()
{
    Console.Clear();
    if (rowl <= pnms.GetLength(0) - 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= pnms.GetLength(1) - 1; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(pnms[i, j]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    row += 1;
}
```

**Edit:** The anwser I requested was

```
for (int i = row; i >= 0; i--;)
```

which was provided by: Pranav Hosangadi

But I accepted the anwser from Caius Jard, as he went over and beyond what I asked for.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "add columns below..." columns are vertical things. Anything below a column is.. the same column

Comment: Please look at the example. I added 1st, 2cnd, 3rd etc for clerification

Comment: Just for reference, it seems that what you call a column, the rest of the world calls a row. You can keep calling it a column if you like, but it will be a source of perpetual confusion for the person from which you seek the help

Comment: What's wrong with iterating in reverse? `for (int i = rowl; i >= 0; i--)`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I keep getting `outOfRange` error. I'll try it again

Comment: Problem you've got is that it will always look crap, because the console just won't redraw fast enough to make it convincing, if you clear it. You'll probably get away with it if you just set the cursor pos and write a single char, then set it again and write another.. Also take a check on how the matrix effect works; characters drop in columns, it doesn't update rows

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks dude. Now it works. Previously I reworked the whole code, and I guess it went wrong somewhere. Add it as an anwser and I'll accept.

Comment: @CaiusJard heh, true. It will never look good. it's a console app =) I'm just doing it for practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go; this is a matrix effect:

```
            int width = 60; //draw 60 columns
            int height = 20; //draw 20 rows

            var chars = "1234567890-=qwertyuiop[]asdfghjkl;'#zxcvbnm,./!\"£$%^&*()_+QWERTYUIOP{}ASDFGHJKL:@~ZXCVBNM<>?".ToCharArray(); //create an array of chars to randomly choose and pump onto screen

            var r = new Random(); //make only one Random. Never make a Random in a loop

            while (true) //forever
            {
                int randCol = r.Next(0, width); //pick which column we will draw now

                for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {              //for every row from top to bottom
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(randCol, i);      //put the cursor there
                    Console.Write(chars[r.Next(chars.Length)]); //pump a random char
                    Thread.Sleep(200);                          //it's a bit fast otherwise
                }
            }
```

I haven't out and out given the solution for your exercise, because it looks like a homework (and I don't do homework), but I hope you can step through this and look at how it's working, and make the adaptations that you need to your program to get the result you're after

Perhaps, for example, you can keep your lines in a 2D buffer, and you can decide on a column randomly (like I did), and you can render it down the screen row by row, by reading down the column (or up), writing to the screen, the same column as you selected from the buffer, then select another column

Perhaps you can periodically insert lines into the buffer (scrolling new data through it).

Perhaps also, yoou can write the char first in white, then later overwrite it in grey just before you write the new char in white (the effect is hard to see when the screen has filled up)

Then you can write multiple chars at different offsets at the same time..

..then you can give it to the peeps at codegolf.se.com and they'll write you a version in like, 15 chars of 05AB1E or something

Comment: Thanks. Tried it out and it looks great. I guess I'm gona have to watch matrix again =) I'll look into how it works. So far, I've given you a +1. I'm going to wait for Pranav to anwser the question, since his code actually solved my problem. If he doesn't post an anwser in a day or so I'm going to accept yours.

Comment: I have no idea what 05ABE is supposed to mean

Comment: Does this really answer the question? Because the rows are not printed in the way the OP asked - they still print from top down, with a new number appearing at the bottom of the column, rather than as if they were "falling", where each number moves down a row as the column is filled.

Comment: Edited my question to also provide the anwser to the question. As there was no other anwser and OP went over and beyond what I asked for, I accepted this anwser.

Comment: Ok, well it's only been an hour but no problem. If it's solved I'll leave it be!

Comment: @DoomBot *"I have no idea what 05AB1E is supposed to mean"* - yeah, i've been looking at golf responses for years, and I still don't know what [it](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E) means ;) (code golf is usually about finding the most compact way of expressing an algorithm in a given language. For example [this](https://tio.run/##ATEAzv9vc2FiaWX//8Kmwqgyw7TigqxSSsK5zrjCudC9LsOBSv//U3RhY2sgRXhjaGFuZ2Uh) 14 byte program that swaps adjacent characters in a string, bested by [this](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9vc2FiaWX//8SHc8KoMsO0w61KwrnOuEr//1N0YWNrIEV4Y2hhbmdlIQ) 10 byte version..

Comment: @DoomBot .. but it was [beaten by Jelly](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/197480/cahartcres-awppnig-character-swapping?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) which can turn `helloworld` into `hleolowlrd` in 7 bytes..